# Information from one site to another

Tags: google-chrome-extension

The main idea: I have one advertisment on one site. On second site I dont have this advertisment, but I need it. Copy/Paste - its a very hard work, because I have many advertisments. So I want to do a chrome extension. I click on **PageAction** on first page, extension with help of jquery takes all information, what I need, and then places this information on second site (in inputs).

In the manifest.json I have:

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [ "http://first.com/*", "http://first.com/*"],
      "js": ["js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js", "js/first.js"]
    }
  ],
```

So, jquery and **first.js** take all information from first site. The next step - its place information on a second site, but how to do this? I have no idea. If I add "second.com" in *matches*, so all js will work on first and second pages. I need **first.js** - **first.com**, **second.js** - **second.com** and second.js takes a information from the first.js.

I dont know, how to do this. Its my first day of working with chrome extensions, may be you know a **more easier way**. I dont want to work with "storange", I have read all docs. Please, help.

Thanks.

Comment: You need to first save the information taken from the first site as JSON and pass it to the background page with message passing. The background page stores that information. In second.js, it requests the background page for the information stored (also with message passing) and convert it back to HTML or DOM and injects it into the page.

Comment: @方觉 and where I need to declare `second.js`?

Comment: As a content script that matches second.com.

Comment: @方觉 content scripts cannot use chrome.* APIs (except for parts of chrome.extension)

Comment: It can use chrome.runtime.sendMessage and other related API to communicate with the background page.